# Remove white space in css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following code where I have 4 sections of a page - a gallery, an ecommerce section, some content and some call to actions.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Gallery</div>
  <div>Ecommerce<br>Ecommerce<br>Ecommerce</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>CTAs</div>
</div>
```

Coming from a mobile first approach, we want the page to flow as it is with the ecommerce section directly under the gallery, but on desktop, we want there to be 2 columns with the gallery and content grouped together and the ecom and ctas group in the second column.

However if we do this using the above code, it will create white space above the content if the ecommmerce section is longer than the gallery, or white space above the CTA section if the gallery is longer than ecommerce section.

Is there any way so that on desktop the content sits directly under the gallery with no white space (ie can I somehow group the two divs so they are one column)?

I thought maybe something using grid areas (but the following makes the content sit on top of the gallery):

```css
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "column1 column2";
  }
  
  .column-1 {
    grid-area: column1;
  }
  
  .column-2 {
    grid-area: column2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column-1">Gallery</div>
  <div class="column-2">Ecommerce<br>Ecommerce<br>Ecommerce</div>
  <div class="column-1">Content</div>
  <div class="column-2">CTAs</div>
</div>
```

If there is a non css grid solution, I will also accept that.  But no fixed heights or absolute positioning as the content is dynamic and there is other content below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only solution is to use extra wrappers and rely on `display:contents`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  border:1px solid;
  margin:5px;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display:contents;
}
.wrapper > div:first-child > div:first-child {
  order:1;
}
.wrapper > div:first-child > div:last-child {
  order:3;
}
.wrapper > div:last-child > div:first-child {
  order:2;
}
.wrapper > div:last-child > div:last-child {
  order:4;
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .wrapper > div {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>Gallery</div>
    <div>Content</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Ecommerce<br>Ecommerce<br>Ecommerce</div>
    <div>CTAs</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>Gallery</div>
    <div>Content<br>Content<br>Content</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Ecommerce</div>
    <div>CTAs</div>
  </div>
</div>
```